# Cross-platform .vimrc/_vimrc

Tags: vim, vimrc, gvimrc

I use vim on windows (GVim portable off a USB stick) and Linux (standard command-line vim) and would like to synchronise my settings (`_vimrc` or `.vimrc`  respectively). As far as I can see (I haven't delved too deeply into it) the only difference should be the shell used for external commands.
TLDR:

1. **Is there a way in a vim script to test which OS it is running on?**
2. **Are there any other incompatibilities between GVim and Linux vim as far as the `vimrc` is concerned?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: @bdecaf thanks, that was part of the question, but the other conflicts could also be an issue if present. I'll take a look

Comment: I have a very similar setup. As far as I can tell (g)vim itself has no problems. On windows many plugins I tried had problems with windows style paths. Also many command line tools which are standard in unix need to be installed and they all have their issues on windows. And I had to set many environment variables in windows to make things work.

Comment: @bdecaf okay, thank you. So as long as anything platform-specific like command-line tools are  handled differently for each platform it should be fine?

Comment: Overall that should be, and I wouldn't expect problems. Unfortunately on windows it's quite a mess on vim variants and implementation of the command line tools - so you will not know for sure till you try it out.

Comment: @bdecaf in terms of "command line tools" would that be external binaries such as `diff`?